# Get Texture location from CC3Vector node location

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, framebuffer, cocos3d

I have a loaded POD file with one node. 
I calculated the correct surface position from touch with the unproject method. Now i want to draw on the texture (stored in Framebuffer) with the `readColorContentFrom` method.

Ho do I get the pixel location of a texture in the `ccColor4B colorArray[]`.

Generally: how can i draw on the texture on a POD with touches? Is this the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered the same question you posted to the cocos3d forum [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/exact-texture-location-from-wold-coordinate/#post-414871).